# Thousand of cache files .HTM

Tags: windows, browser, cache, iis

In our development department, users use w2019 virtual machines. We are observing that every day there a lot of new cache files .HTM in:
C:\Users\iisuserpool\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE

With this content:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="charset=unicode-1-1-utf-8"><!-- saved from url=(0015)assemblybinder: --><html><pre>
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (***) ***

The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/website/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = D:\website\bin
LOG: Dynamic Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\
LOG: Cache Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\
LOG: AppName = 
Calling assembly : *** Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\website\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=
LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Design\v4.0_4.0.0.0__\System.Design.dll.
LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.
</pre></html>
```

How can we prevent it?

Thanks,

Comment: Im going to uninstall IE11 as a first step.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: C:\Users\iisuserpool is the user's pool of IIS website. Everyday it generate more than 2000 HTM files in this location C:\Users\iisuserpool\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE

Comment: Run the Assembly Binding Log Viewer `FUSLOGVW.exe` and check if log binding is enabled.

Comment: That was the solution, many thanks ;)